# Find $\int_2^{2.2}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ given $f(x)=x^4-3x^3+9x^2+22x+6$.

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

$f(x)=x^4-3x^3+9x^2+22x+6$. Find $\int_2^{2.2}f(x)dx$ by finding $f(x-2)$
This is in a non-calculator paper which is why $f(x-2)$ is meant to be obtained (it's supposed to made the maths possible to do in your head)

Am I right in thinking that the integral would change to: $$\int_0^{0.2}f(x-2)dx$$

However, how do you find $f(x-2)$ and what is the result?

Comment: Actually, the integral changes to $\int_0^{0.2} f(x+2)dx$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know calculus, but I can help you when it comes to the function part. You just have to put (x-2) wherever there is an x. So we have

$f(x-2)=$
$$(x-2)^4-3(x-2)^3+9(x-2)^2+22(x-2)+6= x^4-11x^3+31x^2-82x+38 $$.

Comment: how did you get $31x^2$ i got $51x^2$